# C# Sending a web request without throwing an exception on failure

Tags: c#

I am testing a large amount of public proxies for validity.  Optimal throughput is a necessity due to the size of this collection.  This is simple enough to achieve using HttpWebRequest/Task, however, it results in many exceptions being thrown due to the fact that many of the proxies are invalid.  These caught exceptions are causing terrible performance in my application. From my research, I've seen that exceptions have significant performance overhead.

I thought maybe the Socket class would be a good solution, but quickly found that it also throws an exception when it fails to connect to the remote endpoint.  This makes sense, but in my use case, I do not want a failure to connect to result in an exception, similar to how various methods such as TryParse exist in the .NET framework.  As far as I've been able to research, a similar method does not exist for what I am trying to achieve.

I would like to perform a direct system call to perform a web request using C#.  I feel that I am going to need to go to a lower level of abstraction to achieve the behavior I've described, but I am open to and grateful for anyone's input.  If I am correct that system calls will be needed, any example code would be extremely beneficial.

Current implementation:

```
private async Task Validate()
{
    var proxies = new List<string>(); //In actual use, this contains 10,000+ proxies
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var proxy in proxies)
    {
        tasks.Add(IsValid(proxy));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task<bool> IsValid(string proxy)
{
    try
    {
        var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
        req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
        var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync();
        using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var html = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                if (html.Contains("<title>Example Domain</title>"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think your best bet will be to handle the exceptions; log them so that you know which proxies are failing and just continue. Even writing your own implementation of a socket connection, you're likely to still get an error at some point following the failure to connect

Comment: Don't use HttpWebRequest for starters. Use HttpClient, which was released in 2012.. Using the legacy HttpWebRequest offers *no* advantage over the (no longer new) HttpClient class. In .NET Core HttpWebRequest is actually a legacy wrapper over HttpClient, so you'll be using HttpClient one way or another

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would have to create a new instance of HttpClient for each proxy.  HttpClient is recommended to be used as a singleton.

Comment: Is that not a contradiction in terms, @JohnWick?

Comment: @JohnWick no you don't. No it's not. And you're using HttpClient anyway. Because HttpWebRequest is just a legacy wrapper over HttpClient in .Net Core

Comment: @Ortund It is unfortunate indeed, as these exceptions are decreasing my potential throughput by orders of magnitude, due to me having to throttle them just to keep my application from becoming unresponsive due to the large amounts of exceptions.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Noted about HttpWebRequest being a wrapper in .NET Core.  However, using HttpClient isn't going to solve my problem here.  Unless things have changed since I last checked, each individual proxy requires a separate instance of HttpClient, because the proxy is a property of the HttpClientHandler class, which is then passed into the clients constructor.

Comment: @JohnWick it's actually a LOT easier to use multiple proxies with HttpClient and HttpClientFactory. HttpClientFactory takes care of creating a pool of HttpClient instance and *recycling* them, to handle DNS changes. You can configure strongly-typed or named HttpClient instances, each with its own configuration. This means that you only need to configure clients and proxies just once instead of creating an HttpWebRequest from scratch, and only have to request a client by name each time you want to call a specific API

Comment: @JohnWick you haven't explained the actual problem yet (using different proxies per HTTP endpoint). You didn't ask about that problem, you asked about a failure in the assumed solution. This is called [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Using HttpClient means you don't have to wait for DNS resolution on each call, significantly reducing overhead. Using an HttpClientFactory means you can configure multiple endpoints, with different credentials, proxies and even retry settings (if you add Polly)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your valuable input.  The problem is, the UI of my application is hanging due to the large amounts of exceptions being thrown in a short amount of time, despite the requests being performed on non-UI threads (Task.Run).  From what I can tell, the exceptions are causing instability in my entire application.  I am wondering if making direct system calls to make these requests would enable me to eliminate said exceptions, allowing me to have a high throughput without sacrificing responsiveness.

Answer (score 2):

It could reduce the number of exceptions when you use PING protocol first, to see if the proxy server under test is actually online. That will catch a lot of easy cases. For PING, you won't need exception handling. Also you could perform both protocols in parallel.

Comment: Hi @Goodies, I actually just tried this!  Unfortunately, I can't ping specific ports using the Ping class, it seems to use the ICMP protocol.  I'd imagine this might be to prevent port scanning, which I am not trying to do.  But yeah, I need to know if the public proxies port is open (without throwing an exception).  While I can atleast see if the IP is pingable, that doesn't completely solve the problem.  It's certainly a good method of reducing the amount of exceptions thrown, though.

Comment: I've built an application checking a link list, to dynamically weed out the links that don't work anymore. In 9 of 10 cases there was no extra test needed. But you're right, a ping will indicate only if a web server is switched on an connected to its domain. Not if a port is open for requests. Btw in my little application, the stage that consumed most time was resolve and connect, not a connection error exception. I reused the IP resolved by the PING to skip the DNS on the second (http) test.

Comment: It's very likely I'll just end up doing this, when I was just testing a moment ago, I was doing a test just sending many requests through 127.0.0.1:8888 (Fiddler proxy), which was passing the ping, but throwing an exception on the actual web request as I had fiddler turned off.  When testing actual proxies, this does help very much.